# Is there any point in converting value to bool in an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code base littered with statements like this:

```
if bool(some_object.some_value):
    do_something(some_object.some_value)
```

My understanding is that converting an object into a boolean is already done automatically by the if statement, so it's pointless to explicitly convert the value to a boolean.

Am I correct in assuming that this block of code is functionally identical?

```
if some_object.some_value:
    do_something(some_object.some_value)
```

Can I confidently remove all the calls to `bool()` without breaking anything, or are there any subtle differences between how `if` and `bool()` interprets values as booleans I should be wary of?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool) there isn't any difference. *"The bool() method converts a value to Boolean (True or False) using the standard truth testing procedure."*  You would use `bool()` when you want to store the result of the evaluation in a variable to be used later.  Otherwise, it's just redundant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) seems to confirm it. Go ahead and make it an answer and I'll mark this as resolved.

Comment: Wow, the docs are really making this more difficult than it needs to be...

Comment: @Aran-Fey: The docs are probably complicated by the fact that Python is not a language having a formal written standard, but rather a defacto one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool) there isn't any difference. "The bool() method converts a value to Boolean (True or False) using the standard truth testing procedure."

You would use bool() when you want to store the result of the evaluation in a variable to be used later. Otherwise, it's just redundant.

Comment: Right, so we know [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) uses the [standard truth testing procedure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth), but what about `if`? The [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) links to [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans) for the definition of true/false, which states that "False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets)" are considered false.

Comment: (cont'd) (And, of course, classes can customize their truth value by implementing `__bool__`.) Which, fortunately, is exactly the same definition as the standard truth testing procedure gives.